# 'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

estoy intentando generar un xml de mi registro de ususario en django, tengo la función:

````
```
def my_serialize(request):
  query_set = User.objects.all()
  xml = render_to_string('xml_template.xml', {'query_set': query_set})
  return xml
 ```
````

con su respectiva url y siguiente plantilla xml:

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <textFields>
        {% for object in query_set %}
         <textField id="{{object.id}}" text="{{object.first_name}}" />
        {% endfor %}
    </textFields>
```

cuando, accedo a user/xml me da el siguiente error: "'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'".Como pudiera solucionarlo... Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que devolver una respuesta HTTP no un String.

Tendrías que poner:

```
return HttpResponse(render_to_string('xml_template.xml', {'query_set': query_set})
```